# I am trying to enable cash on delivery only for Retailer group

Tags: magento, payment, observer-pattern, magento-1.9, observers

I am trying to doing disable cash on delivery for a particular customer group, i want to enable only one payment method like cash on delivery only for a Retailer, in magento, i have tried some options but it is throwing some errors. i have followed these links [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67982/how-to-disable-cash-on-delivey-on-specific-product-type)

config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config>
    <modules>
        <Suyati_Cashondelivery>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
        </Suyati_Cashondelivery>
    </modules>

    <!-- <global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_payment_methods>Suyati_Cashondelivery_Block_Methods</onepage_payment_methods>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
    </global> -->
    <events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Suyati_Cashondelivery_model_observer</class>
            <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
            </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>

     </config>
```

observer.php

```
    class Suyati_Cashondelivery_model_observer
    {
        public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance(); 
         $role = "Retailer";
        /*   get  Quote  */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

            /* Disable Your payment method for   adminStore */


               if($role == "Retiler"){
allow cash ondelivery // am not sure which code needs to be written here.

            }
        }
```

Comment: check with http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/netz98magento/extension/7590/n98_customergroupcheckout

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`if ($role == 'Retailer') {
     $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
     $result->isAvailable = true;
}`